# How to initialize data to variable with same name as constructor variables?

Tags: kotlin, class, constructor

I have a variable `foo:String` declared in `Kotlin` and in constructor I want to pass variables with same name as `foo:String` but I don't know how to make both variables different from each other as in `C#` we use `this.foo` for class variables

I am expecting:

```
class Product
{
    lateinit var productName:String
    constructor(productName:String)
    {
        this.productName = productName
    }
}
```

Please guide me how to do it in `Kotlin`.

Comment: Just do `class Product(var productName:String)`? You do not need a secondary constructor.

Comment: @Sweeper actually i have more variables in my actual code but here my code is concise i need secondary constructor in my actual code

Comment: Okay, then please [edit] your question with a minimal example that actually demonstrates your problem. The current example is clearly *too* minimal that it does not demonstrate the problem that you are having.

Comment: Are you just asking how to reference the class's `productName` field when there's a constructor or function parameter with the same name? You do it exactly like in your example, use `this.productName` to refer to the class instance explicitly. Your code runs fine! https://pl.kotl.in/HgjwEd8l3 (Shouldn't be `lateinit` since you're assigning a value at construction time anyway but it still works)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You use this like you used in C#

This sample shows how to do this for primary constructor

```
class Product{
   private val name : String
   constructor(name : String) {
      this.name = name
   }
}
```

And this is sample for second constructor:

```
class Product (){
    private var name : String = ""
    constructor(name : String) : this() {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Comment: That first example doesn’t have a primary constructor at all, nor should such a verbose way of defining a class be used when all it does is pass through arguments as direct property initializers.

Comment: The first example is a rewrite of `(class Product (val name : String))`. They are the same. As you can see it has a constructor with a string parameter and you can not call a default constructor. for more info please see [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#creating-instances-of-classes)

Answer (score 0):

That entire class can be written as just

```
class Product(var productName: String)
```

Comment: i know this method but i want to learn how to do it in kotlin because i am very new to kotlin

Comment: @RisenStar then what's the problem? I agree with Sweeper that you should show a minimal example that still shows the problem. My code solves your example problem but clearly is not your actual problem